# Create TABLE failed. 3706: Syntax error: expected something between the 'AS' and the word 'Identity'

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am creating a table in Tera data with an identity column that can be optional during new record insertion using below query

```sql
CREATE SET TABLE dbname.Table1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
    (id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
    (START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 0
MAXVALUE 1000000
NO CYCLE),
    col1 INTEGER,
    col2 INTEGER,
    col3 INTEGER,
    col4 TIMESTAMP ,
    col5 VARCHAR(255),
    col6 TIMESTAMP ,
    col7 INTEGER)
PRIMARY INDEX ( Id, col1, col2, col3);
```

Error:

```
Create TABLE failed. 3706: Syntax error: expected something between the 'AS' and the word 'Identity'.
```

https://forgetcode.com/teradata/1244-identity-column#
This website helped me with the syntax of IDENTITY. Also reused some parts of the syntax from existing tables in the db(could not find any tables having Identity already, so I had to write one).

Database version: Teradata 16.10.0207  16.10.02.07

Let me know if you need any more details.
Pretty new to Tera data so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That works for me as is, except for the primary index column. I think the if you use the identity column as the PI, you can't use any other columns in the PI.

Comment: I tried new query with just Id as primary index, it was throwing the same error

Comment: Your identity syntax is correct and should work as-is (of course you should use GENERATED BY DEFAULT for an optional value), but the PI will fail. Btw, `MAXVALUE 1000000` is way to low as values are assigned in blocks (100000 by default) to each AMP. And think twice if you really need an identity column, it's quite uncommon in Teradata.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, Andrew. Turns out I don't have DDL access. I was able to create tables after getting DDL access :)